# facing problem in kali linuix python3-pip

Tags: python, package

I am facing this problem:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate
```

This is error I am  facing

And I have try these commands `apt-get update` && `apt-get upgrade`

But problem isn't solved.

Answer (score 31):

Try these commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I had the exact issue as OP and this answer properly resolves it.

Answer (score 7):

Now, **I had faced that problem**, and **i know the exact cause**.
So, After i've installed Kali 2020.2, i was not able to download any package including the **python3-pip**. After digging some research i found that the problem in my case was with the source repositories list. That are located in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

To fix this go to the sources.list file:

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

And add these lines in the above sources.list file.

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

After that update your package list with.

`sudo apt update`

Then You'll be able to download any package including **python3-pip**.

`sudo apt install python3-pip`

Comment: I installed Kali 2020.2a on Oracle VirtualBox 6.1, with Win 10 Pro as Host OS. I followed the steps in your post and updated my /etc/apt/sources.list. When I run sudo apt update I get errors of type "Failed to fetch http://kali.download/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/source/Sources.gz  Hash Sum mismatch".

Answer (score 1):

Download this file: [get-pip](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

Run the below code in your terminal:

```
python3 get-pip.py
```

Comment: thanks bro so much help me my tool run now again thankuuu.....bro

Comment: If it helped you, choose it as the answer, to help the community.

Comment: Don't know what it really does, got pip3 installed successfully!

Answer (score 0):

Open the file /etc/apt/sources.list

and uncomment following line

`deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free`