# How to install Python package installer PIP on Ubuntu 20.04 Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pip

**Trying to install pip** with **Ubuntu version 20.04**, **Python version** 3.8 on my Oracle virtual box.
Tried everything to install pip but failed

**Steps tried**

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Also tried

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

**Error both times**

> python3-pip is not available but is being used by another candidate. This may mean that the package has been obsolete, has been missing or is only available from another source.
>
> E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate

Comment: You'll probably have better luck asking on ask ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried to use `pip`, without install?

Comment: I tried `pip3 --version`, got error: pip command not found...Also tried `pip --version`, got same error, pip not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

1.vim /etc/apt/sources.list

2.add these lines in the above file.

```
   deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contribs
   deb http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
   deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

3. sudo apt update
4. sudo apt install python3-pip

**Option 2**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

**Option 3**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59922280/11741464

Source:
[facing problem in kali linuix python3-pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59922229/facing-problem-in-kali-linuix-python3-pip)

Comment: This answer is for kali linux.  On ubuntu, you can do `sudo add-apt-repository universe` to access the `python3-pip` package.

Comment: This worked for me on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04.  Apparently doing update/upgrade a 2nd time does the trick