# How to install python3-pip on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-20.04

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a PC. I then tried to get started and install pip for python3. However nothing seemed to work.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

This is the error I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate
```

I have tried the solution proposed by Carlos Sanchez JR.:
[How to install Python package installer PIP on Ubuntu 20.04 Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62125925/how-to-install-python-package-installer-pip-on-ubuntu-20-04-linux)

After following the advice given in the link above I got this error when doing `sudo apt update` :

```
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200423) focal InRelease
Hit:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200423) focal Release
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease              
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                        
Get:5 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Err:5 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ED444FF07D8D0BF6
Get:8 http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Err:8 http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ED444FF07D8D0BF6
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ED444FF07D8D0BF6
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ED444FF07D8D0BF6
E: The repository 'http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Trying  `sudo apt install python3-pip` at this point just gives me the same `E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate` error as before. This is equally true when trying
`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`.

I have found no other solutions to this problem.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/227788 Found in https://askubuntu.com/search?q=E%3A+Package+%27python3-pip%27+has+no+installation+candidate

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/378565

Comment: Nothing seemed to work, I just reinstalled another version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 42):

Try this command

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

**Note**: If you have a fresh install, you need to do this first before trying the above command.

`sudo apt-get update`

Comment: I tried this. It gave me an error. I ended up just installing another version of Ubuntu instead. Now it works just fine.

Comment: That fixed it for me. I had already run update, but I guess I needed to run it again.

Comment: Boom! It was the sudo apt-get update that I was missing! Thank you bro!

Answer (score 24):

Try the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo python3 -m easy_install install pip
python3 -m pip --version
```

Comment: this is the only way on a live cd. apt update has nothing at cdrom://... and python3-pip is not ready yet. But setuptools and easy_install can bring pip3 to work

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

It means you have a fresh install.

try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then just use the below commands, it works fine.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo python3 -m easy_install install pip
python3 -m pip --version
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to enable the universe repository to install the official package for this.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: this is the only one that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem on the AWS EC2.
A simple `sudo apt update` solved the problem.

Comment: If you read the full question (and links provided) you will see it is one of the things I tried. Looking back I think it was probably some sort of hardware problem.

Comment: `sudo apt update` fixed it for me on a new Ubuntu Server 20.04 instance on AWS.

Answer (score 1):

From the error info of the apt-get update. That is caused by the **kali** apt source.
`The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ED444FF07D8D0BF6`

You can run following command at first

```
wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc | apt-key add
```

or

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys ED444FF07D8D0BF6
dpkg --configure -a
```

Then you can run following commands to install pip.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
python3 -m pip3 install -U pip3
```

or:

```
python3 -m pip install -U pip
```

Comment: I tried this. It gave me an error. I ended up just installing another version of Ubuntu instead. Now it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty much the same issue on `Ubuntu 19.04`. Seems the repositories for this version had issues with `sudo apt update` ... ip addresses and repositories where not resolvingl

As I was doing this in a vm, I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and everything worked as it should without issues.

Follow these steps https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/linux/

And then this works.

`sudo apt install python3-pip`

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1:

To install pip, securely download get-pip.py using curl:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Then run the following command in the folder where you have downloaded get-pip.py:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Warning Be cautious if you are using a Python install that is managed by your operating system or another package manager. get-pip.py does not coordinate with those tools, and may leave your system in an inconsistent state.

---

### Method 2:

#### Be cautious using this method, but it worked for me:

```
cd ~
rm -rf .local
rm -rf .cache
sudo apt get python3-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me(with @G.Pavan Kumar help):

Step1: sudo apt-get update

Step2: sudo apt-get install python3-pip

Step3: sudo apt-get update     (tried to update but i guess didn't go well so i tried to fix the missing updates in the following step)

Step4: sudo apt-get update --fix-missing