# pip module is not installed

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, python-3.10

If I try to use pip, it says it is not installed. If I import it, it says no module named symbol. If I try importing symbol, it says no module named symbol. I don't know what to do. My OS is Ubuntu 22.04 jammy jellyfish and it is up to date. It has python 3.10.4.

Comment: At the risk of stating the painfully obvious, have you tried installing the pip module?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. You need to provide a [mre], which means the exact commands you're running and the [full error messages with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). You can [edit] your post. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Did you just upgrade to 22.04? Did you upgrade pip along with it? If not, how did you install pip in the first place?

Comment: This should be very similar to what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62125925/16775594

Answer (score 0):

Try typing pip in Terminal if it gives you an error you need to install pip. Otherwise, make sure the module/library you are working with supports your version.

Comment: Version of what, sorry?

Comment: The version of the module/library sometimes libraries don't work with certain versions of python.

Comment: Which module/library? `pip` or `symbol`?

Comment: The module/library `symbol`

Comment: Just wondering. How do I do this?

Comment: @AnhadChugh can you send pip link of what you trying to install